# Extract identifiers as a string containing the word "the" from an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a function that accepts 4 IDs. I need to pass it all IDs as a string, which contain the word "the".

I tried to output all elements using JQuery and this algorithm:

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="the"]');

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Outputs items that I can't convert to a string with `toString()` and split with `splice()`.

Comment: You want to print the part after `the` in the id?

Comment: I want to get the whole ID as a string. For example, I have 8 IDs in the file "the-*-name" (instead of * any name). I want the full ID and pass it to the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct. You were just one step away.

Once you've selected the elements are are looping through them, use the `id` property to get the element's ID. You can then split the ID by a space and get the second item to get the part after "the."

```js
var arr = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="the"]');

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const id = arr[i].id.split(" ")[1]
    console.log(id)
}
```

```html
<div id="the one"></div>
<div id="the two"></div>
<div id="the three"></div>
```